# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to create children inside a router. However, i'm not able to render the child component inside the application.

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a routerLink="/portal/home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/portal/courses">Cursos</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="">Ferramentas</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="">Central de Ajuda</a></li>
</ul> 
<router-outlet name="dash"></router-outlet>
```

Above we can see part of my html with the router-outlet.

Below the routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'portal'
  },
  {
    path: 'portal',
    component: PortalComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        outlet:'dash'
      },
      {
        path: 'courses',
        component: CoursesComponent,
        outlet:'dash'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
];
```

Here we cannot see the other components because i'm trying to simplify the code here. When i try to click into courses, the error is:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: portal/courses

I also have another page where i set a router-outlet to handle the above code. Check:

```
<main id="main">
<div id="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

<aside id="main-chat">
  <chat-dialog></chat-dialog>
</aside>
  </main>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the directive and the target route in brackets

```
<li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/portal/home']">Início</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="['/portal/courses]'">Cursos</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="">Ferramentas</a></li>
<li><a [routerLink]="">Central de Ajuda</a></li>
```

Comment: To add to @funkizer.  Here's a link to angular docs showing it without: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I'm guessing there's a typo in the real router config path as @joaovictortinoco  says he edited the code for the example. Or something wrong with other routes that are not listed here.

Comment: Nope. not working either. I'm gonna update with full code

Answer (score 0):

For me the routerLink was not in the bracket so I got the error.
Put the routerLink inside the bracket:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a routerLink="/portal/home">Início</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/portal/courses">Cursos</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="">Ferramentas</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="">Central de Ajuda</a></li>
</ul> 
<router-outlet name="dash"></router-outlet>
```

Other thing to point out is check that your `app.module.ts` imports your routing Module class.
Your `routing.ts` should look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import....

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'portal'
  },
  {
    path: 'portal',
    component: PortalComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        outlet:'dash'
      },
      {
        path: 'courses',
        component: CoursesComponent,
        outlet:'dash'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: true }
      )
  ],

  exports: [ RouterModule ]

})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

Your `app.module.ts` should be like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
....


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```